# Floating window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed a floating window with the help of below theme :

```
<style name="MyFloatingWindow">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
</style>
```

My activity's layout has width height as fill parent. But still the behavior is not consistent. On gingerbread its working fine but on ice-cream sandwich, there is a lot of top margin left which I don't want. I want my floating window to spawn full screen on all devices. Can anyone help?